# SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR: 0xC0202009

Tags: ssis, ssms, bids

I created a new package today, it gets info passed down from a Master package that runs other packages as well. My master package pulls the connection info from a config file at runtime. Protection level = DontSaveSensitive. Using Windows Authentication. It works fine locally but when I run it from a job it gives me the error below.

Any ideas or constructive comments are welcome!

> Code: 0xC0202009     Source: DFT - Insert Into StageSites Source DB TEICommon [1]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E14.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Statement(s) could not be prepared.".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Invalid column name 'SuspendedDate'.".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Invalid column name 'FirstShipmentDate'.".  End Error  Error: 2016-10-28 10:38:02.50     Code: 0xC004706B     Source: DFT - Insert Into StageSites SSIS.Pipeline     Description: "component "Source DB TEICommon" (1)" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".  End Error  Error: 2016-10-28 10:38:02.50     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: DFT - Insert Into StageSites SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2016-10-28 10:38:02.50     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: DFT - Insert Into StageSites      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error

Update: [Fixed]
I solved the issue by updating my schema in the database my ETL query was pulling from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your actual errors:

> "Invalid column name 'SuspendedDate'.".
>
> "Invalid column name 'FirstShipmentDate'.".

You are querying a table (in the component `Insert Into StageSites`) , expecting those columns to exist when they do not.   Since you say it works locally but not from a job, the most likely explanation is that your DataSource is connecting to a different server when the job runs it than the one it connects to locally.  Check the connection string in the .config file on the server that the job points to.